# How to write to the ID3 tag WFED URL frame using Python 3.7 and Mutagen on a Windows 10 PC

Tags: python, mutagen, id3v2, python-3.7, id3-tag

I have been creating an MP3 tag editor with Python 3.7 and Mutagen on a Windows 10 PC. I would like to write to the URL frame WFED but it does not respond. I have been able to successfully update another URL frame, WXXX using the code below.

The code below works for WXXX

```
new_url = unicode("http://url.com").encode('raw_unicode_escape').decode("utf-8") 
tags.add(WXXX(encoding=0, url=new_url))
```

The code below does not work on WFED

```
new_feed = unicode("http://url.com").encode('raw_unicode_escape').decode("utf-8")
tags.add(WFED(encoding=0, url=new_feed))
```

Can anyone provide any guidance on how I can write to WFED?

Comment: I haven't used Mutagen for a while, but I think your problem is that, because WFED is not a standard frame, Mutagen doesn't know what format it is, and therefore assumes it's a text field, not a url field.

Comment: If I'm right, you can monkeypatch mutagen's dict of frames to tell it about WFED. Which may sound hacky, but the only clean solution is to build a url-link frame in raw bytes.

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, `WFED` is not a standard ID3v2.x frame

See ID3.org:

- [ID3 tag version 2.3.0 frames](http://id3.org/id3v2.3.0)
- [ID3 tag version 2.4.0 frames](http://id3.org/id3v2.4.0-frames)

Since you are adding a URL, you are better off sticking with `WXXX`, which ID3 defines as "*User defined URL link frame*".

Or, alternatively, you can use `WOAF`, `WOAR`, `WOAS`, or `WORS` frames to store the URL.

Answer (score 0):

Not only is `WFED` not a standard frame, but it doesn't even seem to have the standard format for a `W...` frame!

`WXXX` frames have an encoding field but `W...` frames do not. In ID3, URLs are always encoded in ISO-8859-1 and thus don't need an encoding field. The reason `WXXX` does have one is for its description field.

But with `WFED`, which I believe is an undocumented Apple iTunes extension, every MP3 file I have with this frame begins with a NULL byte, followed by the URL in ASCII (or ISO-8859-1), which makes me think Apple made the `WFED` frame use a `T...` frame format rather than a `W...` frame format.

I haven't tested with other ID3 reading/writing tools or libraries, but Exiftool does report every `WFED` as being blank because it follows the actual standard.

So yes maybe the problem is that Mutagen doesn't support `WFED` or maybe it expects it to follow the `W...` standard format and your software the uses the frame expects it to be in the undocumented format. Check your file in a hex editor to see if Mutagen changes it.